# docker-compose service name problem using mongo official image

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I followed  [official mongo image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) description trying to using it with *docker-compose*.But i've noticed that the mongo service name **can not** be the same as the image name.Here is the situation:

1. created a **docker-compose.yml** file which filled with this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

2. execute docker-compose

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

Then the error appears:

```
Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/"
mongo-express_1  | (node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.
mongo-express_1  |     at Connection.messageHandler (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:364:19)
mongo-express_1  |     at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
```

But when I change the service name **mongo** to **myMongo**,it just work out!:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  myMongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@myMongo:27017/
```

So, where am i wrong?

Comment: Your first example Just Works for me when I run, with no changes. Can you tell us more about the environment in which you're running these services?

Comment: @larsks , Hi , my environment information:

Docker version 20.10.12 ;

docker-compose version 1.28.5;

Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04

Comment: @larsks, i upgrade my docker version to 20.10.17 and docker compose to 2.6.0, and  it worked out. thanks.